# Escrever uma lista de string em um arquivo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tenho uma lista e eu queria escrever em um outro arquivo

```
["AMANDA,"JULIANA","VANESSA","PATRICIA"]
```

Em um documento usando Python, eu consegui porém o arquivo fica todo junto tipo assim:

```
AMANDAJULIANAVANESSAPATRICIA
```

como eu poderia ajeitar isso?

```
def ordem_txt(palavras):  
       arq = open(palavras, 'r')  
       texto = arq.read()  
       palavras = texto.replace("\n", " ").split(" ")  
       palavras.sort(reverse=False)  
       #print(palavras)  
       return palavras  

def write_txt(palavras, caminho):  
    arq = open(caminho, "w")  
    arq.writelines(palavras)  
    arq.close()
```

Comment: Coloque seu código na pergunta, por favor.

Comment: `arq.writelines()` não adiciona os separadores de linha, você mesmo tem que adicioná-los aos itens da lista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como comentado, a função `writelines` não adiciona nenhum separador entre os valores da lista, então, se a intenção seria escrever uma palavra por linha, você precisa adicionar manualmente o caractere `\n`. Por exemplo:

```
arq.writelines(palavra + '\n' for palavra in palavras)
```

Ou utilizar apenas a função `write` adicionando as quebras de linha com o `join`:

```
arq.write('\n'.join(palavras))
```

[Documentação oficial da `writelines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines):

> **writelines(lines)**: Write a list of lines to the stream. **Line separators
>   are not added**, so it is usual for each of the lines provided to have a
>   line separator at the end.